# Rails Actions for Form Posting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, cakephp

I am using Rails 4 and moved from CakePHP.

I have a User Model and to create a new record it uses two Actions - New and Create.

Now when i want to over ride the default for my app. i would like the users to go to Signup action to create a new user. Now when i have a Server side validation and it fails i am posting the form to lets say "create" action the user is shown in the url

'app.com/user/create' instead of 'app.com/user/signup'

Is there any way to keep the user in the same action instead of have multiple action just to display form and save the form?

```
  # GET /users/new
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  # POST /users
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    if @user.save
      redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

Comment: @arilia thats how the default rails works. where u have one action to show the form and one action to submit to and save the content. but what i wanna do is just have signup action which shows the form and also displays the errors on the same action if the validation fails.

Answer (score 1):

You should simply add a redirect in your create action when the user creation fails.

`redirect_to :back, @user`

I would not recommend using `:back` all the time but this is going to be helpful for now as by understanding the scenario you have mentioned.

Comment: if you see the code the user object is being passed with redirect.

Comment: No, it doesn't work - `wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)` you can only use a record if redirecting to for example a post, `redirect_to post_url(@post)`

Comment: Yeah, i got ya, but we can pass the objects while redirecting to anyother url but not to back,

Comment: I don't think you can.  You can redirect to member routes passing an object, I don't think you'd be able to pass it to any other url because rails wouldn't be expecting it and you'd get wrong number of arguments error.

Answer (score 1):

By default, action `new` just initialize model with-or-without params. Action `create` save model to database. `app.com/user/create` is not RESTful and "Rails Way".

```
users_path #=> app.com/users
new_user_path #=> app.com/users/new
user_path(:id) #=> app.com/user/:id
edit_user_path(:id) #=> app.com/user/:id/edit
# and so on
```

In controllers you can define redirections for every action. For example:

```
def create
  if @user.save
    redirect_to user_path(@user)
  else
    redirect_to :back # return to previous page
  end
end
```

More information about routing here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 1):

I would stick with rails conventions but you should be able to do this if you really wanted

Routes.rb

```
get 'signup', to: 'users#signup'
post 'signup', to: 'users#signup'
```

Controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def signup
    if request.get?
      @user = User.new
    elsif request.post?
      @user = User.new(user_params)
      if @user.save
        redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Signed In'
      else
        #should just render signup as it's signup action
      end
    end
  end
end
```